Type a callable which accepts at least one argument
I was wondering how to type hint a callble that accepts at least one argument.
For example the following callables are acceptable:
def foo(x: int): ...
def bar(x: int, y: float): ...

class Baz:
  def __call__(self, x: int): ...

However, the following function isn't:
def noargs(): ...

I have tried using *args and **kwargs but this enforces the accepted callables to receive them along with the other (actual) arguments.

Even if possible, what's the use of such callable? You can't call it yourself, so why do you need any arguments restriction?

@STerliakov    I wanted to define a DataProcessor type. Since it processes some data it has to accept at least one argument.

@InSync        The difference is that I didn't want the *args, **kwargs in the function definitions.

Callable[Concatenate[int, ...], None] is the same as (v: int, /, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None.

@InSync    Are you sure? What you suggested requires the exact function definition (with *args **kwargs).

Yes, I'm sure. These two types are equivalent.

Whereas by using Concatenate the accepted callables don't have to receive *args and **kwargs.

I'm not sure I understand. Could you make a [mre] demonstrating the difference you are talking about?

I'm using Mypy (and not Pyright) and python 3.9.
Please see the following code sample.
Thanks for the help!

Both F1 and F2 signify a callable that should accept at least one positional argument of type int and any additional arguments. (v: int) -> None does not accept any additional arguments and therefore should not be assignable to them. In any case, Mypy and Pyright agree that F1 and F2 are equivalent; that they chose not to report b: F2 = foo is either a bug or a design choice made for practical purposes (likely the latter).

You can use typing.Concatenate to build a variadic signature.
from collections.abc import Callable, Any
from typing import Concatenate

def foo(f: Callable[Concatenate[int, ...], None]):
    pass

foo accepts a callable that accepts at the very least a (first) argument of type int, with 0 or more additional positional arguments accepted (and returns None).
